# Reordering seq number

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table which contains data similar to this

```
seq Controlid
1   12345
2   12345
5   12345
6   12345
9   12345
10  12345
11  12345
16  12345
1   451251
2   451251
3   451251
```

I am looking for some way of applying a update command that can reorder the seq column for a particular Controlid – So given the Controlid 12345 after said update I would end up with this data like this:

```
seq Controlid
1   12345
2   12345
3   12345
4   12345
5   12345
6   12345
7   12345
8   12345
1   451251
2   451251
3   451251
```

The seq columns datatype is smallint
It would always start from 1

(I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select 
       row_number() over (partition by Controlid order by seq) as seq, Controlid
 from your_table
```

Edit : Since you have no option to use view, try this UPDATE

```
update t1 
set
t1.seq=t2.seq_new from your_table as t1 inner join
(
select 
           row_number() over (partition by Controlid order by seq) as seq_new, seq,
           Controlid
     from your_table
) as t2 on t1.seq=t2.seq and t1.Controlid=t2.Controlid
```

Comment: From the question - "... applying a update command ..." - doesn't look like an `update` to me.

Comment: I would prefer a View with simple SELECT so you do not need to run update whenever there is a missing seq value :)

Comment: That, at least, would be something worth *mentioning* in your answer. Code-only answers tend to be frowned upon.

Comment: Thanks, I too would prefer that but unfortunately the data is being displayed via a 3rd party app, so the data must be changed within the source db table.

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever for your valuable suggestion.

Comment: @Andyww I have edited the reply. Refer the UPDATE statement

Answer (score 0):

After reading Madhivanan's comment, This should work for you.

```
CREATE VIEW YOUR_VIEW_NAME
AS
SELECT O.rn,O.Controlid
from 
(SELECT seq
       ,Controlid
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Controlid order by Controlid ) as rn

FROM ORDER_SEQ) O
```